# How to initialize objects inside constructor of a class using spring framework?

Tags: spring

I have following code in java:

```
public class A{
    private B b;
    private C c;



 public A(){
    b=new B();
    c=new C();
    c.foo(d,e);
    }
}
```

I want to change the constructor such that i dont need to write the constructor at all and rather whenever an object of A is created, the spring configuration do it directly. I am new to spring and dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can harness the dependency injection feature of Spring with the Autowired annotation. It has to be clear though, that in this case all involved class instances are **singletons**!

```
@Component
public class B {
}

@Component
public class C {

    @PostConstruct
    public void foo() {
    }
}

@Component
public class A{

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    private C c;
}
```

If this is not what you want, then Spring is not the right tool for this use case. To get rid of your constructor in `A`, you could use plain Java instead:

```
public class B {
}


public class C {

    public C() {
       foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
    }
}

public class A{

    private B b = new B();

    private C c = new C();
}
```